# Environment variables not working (Next.JS 9.4.4)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables, next.js, contentful

So I'm using the Contentful API to get some content from my account and display it in my Next.Js app (I'm using Next 9.4.4). Very basic here. Now to protect my credentials, I'd like to use environment variables (I've never used it before and I'm new to all of this so I'm a little bit lost).

I'm using the following to create the Contentful Client in my index.js file :

```
const client = require('contentful').createClient({
    space: 'MYSPACEID',
    accessToken: 'MYACCESSTOKEN',
});
```

`MYSPACEID` and `MYACCESSTOKEN` are hardcoded, so I'd like to put them in a .env file to protect them and don't make them public when deploying on Vercel.

I've created a `.env` file and filled it like this :

```
CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID=MYSPACEID
CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN=MYACCESSTOKEN
```

Of course, `MYACCESSTOKEN` and `MYSPACEID` contains the right keys.

Then in my index.js file, i do the following :

```
const client = require('contentful').createClient({
  space: `${process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID}`,
  accessToken: `${process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
});
```

But it doesn't work when I use `yarn dev`, I get the following console error :

```
{
  sys: { type: 'Error', id: 'NotFound' },
  message: 'The resource could not be found.',
  requestId: 'c7340a45-a1ef-4171-93de-c606672b65c3'
}
```

Here is my Homepage and how I retrieve the content from Contentful and pass them as props to my components :

```
const client = require('contentful').createClient({
    space: 'MYSPACEID',
    accessToken: 'MYACCESSTOKEN',
});

function Home(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>My Page</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main id="page-home">
        <Modal />
        <NavTwo />
        <Hero item={props.myEntries[0]} />
        <Footer />
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

Home.getInitialProps = async () => {
  const myEntries = await client.getEntries({
    content_type: 'mycontenttype',
  });

  return {
    myEntries: myEntries.items
  };
};

export default Home;
```

Where do you think my error comes from?

Researching my issue, I've also tried to understand how `api` works in next.js as I've read it could be better to create API requests in `pages/api/` but I don't understand how to get the content and then pass the response into my pages components as I did here.

Any help would be much appreciated!

**EDIT:**

So I've fixed this by adding my env variables to my `next.config.js` like so :

```
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');

module.exports = withSass({
  webpack(config, options) {
    const rules = [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [{ loader: 'sass-loader' }],
      },
    ];

    return {
      ...config,
      module: { ...config.module, rules: [...config.module.rules, ...rules] },
    };
  },
  env: {
    CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
    CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
  },
});
```

Comment: I can get .env.local variables in getServerSideProps() using process.env.VARIABLE_NAME but unable to get them when I submit the form on client side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/environment-variables)

You need to add a next.config.js file in your project. Define env variables in that file and those will be available inside your app.

Comment: Ok so i know what my error was.. I've added it to my `next.config.js` but i did it wrong.. now it works, i'll edit my post. Thanks!

Comment: There is way to directly read .env file in node and browser environment. I didn't get a chance to try that. It was not supported in earlier versions.

Comment: @Perdixo, this is incorrect answer because the suggested way **exposes** credentials. It can be used only for variables that can be openly published.

Comment: I have the same issue that @Perdixo, the problem to me continue being the same, if I add the env to next.config.js I solve the problem, because I really dont know why if I create a .env of any type, the result is always undefined, I'm using next v10, and I want to be sure that my credential are no exposed

Comment: This solution is for old versions. The author of the problem should accept @NikolaiKiselev answer.

Comment: But wouldn't this expose the data on Git?

Comment: This is so wrong

Answer (score 95):

if you are using latest version of nextJs ( above 9 )

then follow these steps :

> 1. Create a **.env.local** file in the root of the project.

> 2. Add the prefix **NEXT_PUBLIC_** to all of your environment variables.

```
eg: NEXT_PUBLIC_SOMETHING=12345
```

> 3. use them in any JS file like with prefix **process.env**

```
eg: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SOMETHING
```

Comment: This was what I needed to do - the NEXT_PUBLIC_ is what I was missing to expose the variable to the browser.

Comment: You save my day! How did u find this??

Comment: I did some research .
Also took help from the original NextJS docs - https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables @HariSetiawan

Comment: You can also check out the official docs - https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables
@SamDoidge

Comment: Restart the server after the change.

Comment: Thanks! save my day still works on 2023

Comment: this exposes your secret key to the public so anyone can access it.   do not do this.   please see the other `/pages/api` answer

Answer (score 24):

You can't make this kind of request from the client-side without exposing your API credentials. You have to have a backend.

You can use Next.js `/pages/api` to make a request to Contentful and then pass it to your front-end.

Just create a `.env` file, add variables and reference it in your API route as following:

```
process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID
```

Since Next.js 9.4 you don't need next.config.js for that.

---

By adding the variables to `next.config.js` **you've exposed the secrets** to client-side. Anyone can see these secrets.

[New Environment Variables Support](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-4#new-environment-variables-support)

[Create a Next.js App with Contentful and Deploy It with Vercel](https://vercel.com/guides/deploying-next-and-contentful-with-vercel)

[Blog example using Next.js and Contentful](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/cms-contentful)

Comment: Restart the server after the change.

Answer (score 19):

I recomended to update at nextjs 9.4 and up, use this example:

```
.env.local
NEXT_PUBLIC_SECRET_KEY=i7z7GeS38r10orTRr1i
```

and in any part of your code you could use:

```
.js
const SECRET_KEY = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SECRET_KEY
```

> note that it must be the same name of the key "**NEXT_PUBLIC_** SECRET_KEY" and not only "SECRET_KEY"

and when you run it make sure that in the log says

```
$ next dev
Loaded env from E:\awesome-project\client\.env.local
ready - started server on http://localhost:3000
...
```

To read more about environment variables see [this link](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser)

Comment: Is this required to use NEXT_PUBLIC

Comment: Note that this approach **does not protect** your secrets - they're visible for anyone in frontend package. To protect your secrets you *must* create a backend function as Nikolai Kiselev already suggested in his response. .env files can be used to store secrets but then *never* prefix them with "NEXT_PUBLIC_" as that makes them visible also to frontend. Without "NEXT_PUBLIC_" prefix the variable will be available only in next.js backend which is what you'd want to.

Comment: Restart the server after the change.

Answer (score 9):

You have to make a simple change in next.config.js

```js
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  env:{
    MYACCESSTOKEN : process.env.MYACCESSTOKEN,
    MYSPACEID: process.env.MYSPACEID,
  }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

change it like this

Comment: Restart the server after the change.

Answer (score 7):

**Don't** put sensitive things in `next.config.js` **however** in my case I have some env variables that aren't sensitive at all and I need them Server Side as well as Client side and then you can do:

```
// .env file:
VARIABLE_X=XYZ

// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    VARIABLE_X: process.env.VARIABLE_X,
  },
}
```

Comment: Restart the server after the change.

Answer (score 5):

Not related to 9.4.4 but faced the same problem of env not loading properly.

Checklist:

- `.env.local` file naming
- make sure `.env.local` is in the root folder. Mine was in `src/.env.local` (This was my problem).
- Prefix `NEXT_PUBLIC_` for **client side** environments variables.
- Reload the environment (Hot reloading does not pick up .env file changes)

Also, Refer to Official Docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables

Answer (score 2):

For me, the solution was simply restarting the local server :)

Gave me a headache and then fixed it on accident.

It did not occur to me that env variables are loaded when the server is starting.

Answer (score 1):

```
  npm i --save dotenv-webpack@2.0.0 // version 3.0.0 has a bug
```

create `.env.development.local` file in the root. and add your environment variables here:

```
 AUTH0_COOKIE_SECRET=eirhg32urrroeroro9344u9832789327432894@@@
 NODE_ENV=development
 AUTH0_NAMESPACE=https:ilmrerino.auth0.com
```

create `next.config.js` in the root of your app.

```
const Dotenv = require("dotenv-webpack");
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve.alias["@"] = path.resolve(__dirname);
    config.plugins.push(new Dotenv({ silent: true }));
    return config;
  },
};
```

However those env variables are gonna be accessed by the server. if you want to use any of the env variables you have to add one more configuration.

```
 module.exports = {
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve.alias["@"] = path.resolve(__dirname);
    config.plugins.push(new Dotenv({ silent: true }));
    return config;
  },
 env: {
   AUTH0_NAMESPACE: process.env.AUTH0_NAMESPACE,
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your secrets in `.env.local` and then do this in your `next.config.js`

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  env: {
    VARIABLE_IN_ENV: process.env.VARIABLE_IN_ENV
  }
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your env variables into next.config.mjs file.

Suppose you have defined a variable name API_PATH in .env file.
Next you have to defined process.env.API_PATH into your next.config.mjs file under env object.

[image]
[image]