# 500 SupabaseUrl is required error when deployed on Netlify

Tags: javascript, netlify, nuxtjs3, supabase, supabase-js

I developed an application using NuxtJs3 + supabase. I am using the `@nuxtjs/supabase` module as well. On my local dev things are working fine but when I deployed this on Netlify, I had the below error-

[image]

I rechecked the environment variables settings at Netlify, and `SUPABASE_URL` and `SUPABASE_KEY` both are present.

[image]

On local my `.env` file does look like this as mentioned in the [document](https://supabase.nuxtjs.org/get-started#installation)-

```
SUPABASE_URL=
SUPABASE_KEY=
```

I have browsed a few issues on GitHub as well, mostly revolving around the `.env` debugging ways which I already verified.
Here are a few-

1. [Error: supabaseUrl is required (supabase) postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68239168/error-supabaseurl-is-required-supabase-postgresql)
2. https://www.reddit.com/r/Supabase/comments/13ayvr2/error_supabaseurl_is_required/
3. https://github.com/orgs/supabase/discussions/3218
4. https://community.fly.io/t/supabaseurl-is-required/18010

Can anyone please help in debugging this issue?