# I am having issue with my image src in next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, frontend, sanity

I am using Sanity image url in my project and I am getting this error in my console page that says

> next-dev.js?3515:25 Warning: Prop src did not match.
>
> Server:"https://cdn.sanity.io/images/jbcyg7kh/production/4f6d8f5ae1bed2647201bfcaed2f270897b92306-800x533.jpg"
>
> Client: "https://cdn.sanity.io/images/jbcyg7kh/undefined/4f6d8f5ae1bed2647201bfcaed2f270897b92306-800x533.jpg"

```js
import sanityClient from "@sanity/client";
import  imageUrlBuilder  from "@sanity/image-url";

export const client = sanityClient({
    projectId:"projectId",
    dataset:process.env.NEXT_SANITY_DATASET,
    useCdn: true,
    apiVersion:"2022-05-13"
});

const builder = imageUrlBuilder(client)
  
export const urlFor= (source) =>builder.image(source)
```

```js
import Link from "next/link";
import React from "react";
import { urlFor } from "../lib/client";

function Product({ product: { name, image, price, description, slug } }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Link href={`/product/${slug.current}`}>
        <div>
          <img src={urlFor(image[0])} alt="" />
          <h4>{name}</h4>
          <p>₦{price}</p>
          <p>{description}</p>
        </div>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Product;
```

Comment: You have the use the `NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix in your environment variable name to expose it to the browser. See [Environment variables not working (Next.JS 9.4.4)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65799867/1870780).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `urlBuilder` builds the URL builder from `sanityClient`. Judging by the pattern of the URLs,

> Server:"https://cdn.sanity.io/images/jbcyg7kh/production/4f6d8f5ae1bed2647201bfcaed2f270897b92306-800x533.jpg"

> Client:"https://cdn.sanity.io/images/jbcyg7kh/undefined/4f6d8f5ae1bed2647201bfcaed2f270897b92306-800x533.jpg"

You can see that server has `process.env.NEXT_SANITY_DATASET` set, while client does not. You can add this environment variable by following the steps [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables).