# Is it secure to expose secret keys to a next.js app via environment variables?

Tags: webpack, next.js, environment-variables

As I take it, environment variables prefixed with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` will be substituted by their respective values in the resulting bundle.

Is it safe to supply things like API keys, OAuth secrets and the like using `NEXT_PUBLIC_*` variables or can an end user theoretically access these secret values? If this is the case, then what is the recommended approach to circumventing this potential security issue?

Thank you all for clarification.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62387803/14047838

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`NEXT_PUBLIC_` environment variable prefixes should *only* be used for values which are non-sensitive, and as you pointed out, which you're comfortable with being present in the final bundle. Prefixing any sensitive keys or secret environment variables with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` is a security risk. Those values should only be accessible to next.js at build time or server-side.

Consider using Next.js [API routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) to isolate any service-oriented business logic to the server-side of things.