# Next js Environment variables not working on axios patch request

Tags: javascript, axios, next.js

I am having issues passing my environment variables as the url and headers for my axios patch request

```
const axios = require("axios");

export const  handleSubmit = async (formValue, uniquePageName) => {

await axios
  .patch(process.env.INTERNAL_RETAILER_CONFIG_UPDATE, formValue, {
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":process.env.INTERNAL_RETAILER_CONFIG_UPDATE,
        "x-auth-token":process.env.INTERNAL_TOKEN,
        retailername: uniquePageName,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  })
  .then((res) => {
    return res.data;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
};
```

I have moved this function inside the api folder and I am calling it on my submit button for on the form. I have attached the error on the console.

[image]

Comment: In Next.js, you have to add the `NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix to environment variables to expose them to the browser. See [Environment variables not working (Next.JS 9.4.4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62386582/environment-variables-not-working-next-js-9-4-4) and https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser.

Answer (score 0):

reqiure is not supported in browsers

use `import axios from 'axios'`

Comment: I don't know what framework you are using, but I still recommend using import to try

Comment: Its in the title, Next.js

Comment: Using import did not fix the issue