Next.js Appwrite "TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL'" but works when given directly
I am following along an YouTube video by JS Mastery on their HealthCare application using Next.js and Appwrite. I got my API keys from Appwrite cloud and added them to the .env.local file. But when I run my project, I get the following error,
TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL
    at Users.create (users.mjs:77:17)
    at createUser (patient.actions.ts:6:37)
    at onSubmit (PatientForm.tsx:43:42)
    at eval (index.esm.mjs:2256:23)

The code for creating an user looks like this,
import { ID, Query } from "node-appwrite"
import { users } from "../appwrite.config"

export const createUser = async (user: CreateUserParams) => {
    try {
        const newUser = await users.create(
            ID.unique(), 
            user.email, 
            user.phone, 
            undefined, 
            user.name
        )
        console.log(newUser)

    } catch(error: any) {
        if (error && error?.code === 409) {
            const documents = await users.list([
                Query.equal('email', [user.email])
            ])

            return documents?.users[0]
        } else {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
}

and the user is exposed from this code,
import * as sdk from "node-appwrite";

export const {
    NEXT_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT: ENDPOINT,
    PROJECT_ID,
    API_KEY,
    DATABASE_ID,
    PATIENT_COLLECTION_ID,
    DOCTOR_COLLECTION_ID,
    APPOINTMENT_COLLECTION_ID,
    NEXT_PUBLIC_BUCKET_ID: BUCKET_ID,
} = process.env;

const client = new sdk.Client();

client.setEndpoint(ENDPOINT!).setProject(PROJECT_ID!).setKey(API_KEY!);

export const databases = new sdk.Databases(client);
export const users = new sdk.Users(client);
export const messaging = new sdk.Messaging(client);
export const storage = new sdk.Storage(client);

the .env.local file,
PROJECT_ID=************
API_KEY=************************************
DATABASE_ID=************
PATIENT_COLLECTION_ID=************
DOCTOR_COLLECTION_ID=************
APPOINTMENT_COLLECTION_ID=************
NEXT_PUBLIC_BUCKET_ID=************
NEXT_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT=https://cloud.appwrite.io/v1

I've double checked the API values and they are what they should be. To check if the values are wrong I tried replacing the variables names with the actual .env values and that works fine.

client
    .setEndpoint("https://cloud.appwrite.io/v1")
    .setProject("***************")
    .setKey("*****************);

Is there anything I am missing? Please let me know how to solve this issue. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.
Link to youtube video

This part of the error at Users.create (users.mjs:77:17)indicates that you should add code inside users.mjs to your question. BR

I do not have an users.mjs file though. The only places that refer to users are the appwrite.config file and the createUser function file.

Related question about environment variables: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62386582/14072498
Please read the comments in the highest ranked answer, and look at the second highest ranked answer.

I read through the question and the answers too as you mentioned, unfortunately they don't help. I am able to access the variables in the server, and the user creation happens in the server. However exposing them as env variables is somehow causing a type error. That's the problem I am facing

add "use server" on top of patients.actions.ts file. By adding "use server", you're telling Next.js that all the functions in this file should be executed on the server, never on the client. Server-side code can access all environment variables, including those not prefixed with NEXT_PUBLIC_. This is why your PROJECT_ID, API_KEY, and DATABASE_ID became accessible.
 "use server"
    
    import { ID, Query } from "node-appwrite";
    import { users } from "../appwrite.config";
    
    export const createUser = async (user: CreateUserParams) => {    
      try {
        const newuser = await users.create(
          ID.unique(),
          user.email,
          user.phone,
          undefined,
          user.name
        );
      } catch (error: any) {
        if (error && error?.code === 409) {
          const documents = await users.list([Query.equal("email", [user.email])]);
          return documents?.users[0];
        }
        console.error("An error occurred while creating a new user:", error);
      }
    };


I was stuck so long on this. Add this to the top of patients.actions.ts:
"use server"

Thank you so much, that works. Thanks to @Krishnadev. V I now know why it works. It's weird that it was not mentioned in the video though.

this worked for me; update the next config to this
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    env: {
        PROJECT_ID: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
        API_KEY:process.env.API_KEY,
        DATABASE_ID:process.env.DATABASE_ID,
        PATIENT_COLLECTION_ID:process.env.PATIENT_COLLECTION_ID,
        DOCTOR_COLLECTION_ID:process.env.DOCTOR_COLLECTION_ID,
        APPOINTMENT_COLLECTION_ID:process.env.APPOINTMENT_COLLECTION_ID,
      BUCKET_ID:process.env.BUCKET_ID,
        ENDPOINT:process.env.ENDPOINT
    }
};

export default nextConfig;


Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. I changed the config and relaunched the server but it still fails as before.
